# solar panels connected in series and parallel

Tags: solar-cell

Can I get 500 kW from solar panels using series and parallel operation?

If I connect 18 panels each of 250 watts 24 volts in series to get 415 volt direct current and 116 panels in parallel to get 1205 amperes, then combine it into series and parallel. Can i get 500000 watts from it ?
Since,
Power= Voltage*Current
(excluding all losses)
=> Power= 415*1205
=> Power= 518750 watts.

And after converting direct current to alternating current will there be a power change?

Since in electrical the above equation \$P=VI\$ is possible mathematically, is it also possible practically?

Comment: If you connect in parallel 116 lots of (18 panels in series), then you get 522kW (nominal) from your 2088 panels. That's a substantial solar farm. Note that actual power output depends on latitude, weather, time of day.

Comment: I believe there is some gotcha with the fact that your panels will never be fully identical and not all will be equally lit. This will probably do with a short string of panels, but I doubt it is that easy with 500kW installation.

Comment: You may be attempting black magic. Your question may be read several ways. People are answering it as if you had a full bank of panels but that may not be what you mean. | Pabel watts or kW add. to get 500 kW with 0.25 kW panels you meed 500/.250 = 2000 panels. | You CANNOT use 18 + 116 panels = 134 x 250 W panels to get 500 kW. Alas :-)

Comment: Anyone messing with 1/2 MW shouldn't be asking basic questions here.

Comment: What you are trying is impossible. If you have 2 sources of energy connected to the same wire, they still act as independent sources of energy. Their power will in no way be mutiplied by each other. It is impossible to create more energy than panels can give.
  

In terms of energy: you have 134 panels of 250W, so you will get 33kW from them at most, in an Ideal scenario. In reality, you´ll hardly get past 27kW because of all losses envolved.

Answer (score 1):

> Since in electrical the above equation P= V*I is possible mathematically, is it also possible practically ??

Basically yes. That equation exists because it matches real world observations. However, you must also account for other equations that match real world observations. Here's one that is especially relevant in this context:

$$ P = I^2 R $$

This is [Joule's first law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%27s_first_law). If you have 1205A, R better be *very small*. R here is the resistance of the wire carrying your 1205A. Let's say it's just \$1m\Omega\$. Then:

$$ P = (1205A)^2 \cdot 0.001\Omega \approx 1452W $$

That's an awful lot of power to be wasted just in the wire. It's probably getting pretty hot.

It's usually easier and more economical to make wires with strong insulation that won't break down under high voltage than it is to make wires with low resistance, since this requires large amounts of expensive metals. Thus, when people have a lot of electrical energy to transfer, as a power plant does, they tend to use high voltage rather than high current.

Regarding the calculation of how much power you can get out of some number of solar panels, you need not make the math so complex. If one panel gets you 250W, then two gives you twice that much. I'm not sure how you are "combining in series and parallel", but to get 518750 watts, you need, one way or another:

$$ \frac{518750W}{250W} = 2075 \text{ panels} $$

If you connect the panels in series, then their voltages add, but the current remains the same. If you connect them in parallel, then the currents add, but the voltage remains the same.

> And after converting direct current to alternating current will there be a power change ?

There is nothing that makes AC or DC inherently have more or less power than the other. However, any way you might realize such a conversion will involve some losses, so the output electrical power will be somewhat less than the input power, with the difference likely converted to heat in your conversion device.

Answer (score 1):

No.  With 134 total panels of 250W each, you can get a maximum of 134 x 250W = 33,500W.

Dividing them into two different-size banks and then trying to somehow multiply the voltage of one bank times the current of the other makes no sense, and it doesn't work.  Solar panels are a little like batteries (although batteries are "voltage sources" and panels are "current sources").  You can wire them in series, pr in parallel, or in series-parallel.  You can't multiply one battery times another.